# Why we add a 'wrapper' element in web development

Tags: javascript, html, web

just like:

```
<div class="wrapper">some html text</div>
```

just don't know why we need it.

Comment: Give the context? Is it for a sticky footer or something?

Comment: Voted to move to Programmers Echange (Q&A for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be required if you wish to apply some css to `some html text` or if you want to manipulate it (using javascript etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It is mainly used to set **custom width** of the page. If you didn't use one, you won't be able to enforce width on `<body>` tag. For example, this won't work:

```
body { width:960px; }
```

Comment: As an addendum to this, you *can* set the width in the body in all browsers > IE7 quirksmode. IE7 standards mode and above and every modern browser supports this, you do this for the tiny portion of the global population clinging to IE6. Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/nwellcome/xhJe8/